# Company wants to negotiate lower salary after signed offer

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation, employment-agreement

I got an offer from a consulting company, signed it, and got it signed from them.

Now, their recruiter called me and said if I was open for negotiation. They want to decrease my salary.

They said it's because the client, for which I'll be working, wants to renegotiate with them.

Sound weird? How should I answer?

**PS**. I think the contract that I signed with the company allows them to get a contract with a client, which is not signed yet.

Comment: did you already have a job when you signed on with this new company?

Comment: @user1666620, I still have. I didn't resign yet.

Comment: Are you an at-will or contract employee?

Comment: @jcmack, right now at-will, but offer for contract

Comment: @Alexan I'm not a lawyer, but I recommend looking at the details of your contact. Typically for contact position, the employer needs to honor the terms of the contact and give you amble notice should they want to amend the contract.

Comment: Happened to me once.

Comment: @jcmack, from agreement: "Any changes in compensation must be made by a written attachment to this agreement as an addendum."

Comment: @PM77-1, can you give details?

Comment: Don't bother with trying to "enforce" the contract, it is pointless and costly for you to even try. Rescind your acceptance, be glad that you didn't leave your current job yet, and make sure the word gets around about what they tried to do to you.

Comment: @teego1967, so should I consider contract is canceled?

Comment: @Alexan Sounds like pretty standard contract language. The contract isn't "cancelled," but an addendum could modify the terms of the original contract or add new terms. Technically, the new contracting employers needs to uphold the original terms, but seems like more trouble than its worth to me. I recommend walking away this new job at this point.

Comment: @jcmack, "This agreement shall be subject to termination by either COMPANY or the EMPLOYEE at anytime upon (10) business day's written notice, with or without a cause." Should I give notice?

Comment: No, you should not simply consider the contract cancelled. However, you should seriously consider cancelling it.

Comment: Forget about "the contract". It means nothing. The main thing here is an utter violation of good faith on the part of the potential employer. It was a dishonorable "bait-and-switch." If they do this before you even start working for them, imagine what they will try once you've left your current job and are on their bench.

Comment: Somebody messed up the math, and they are not making a tidy profit with you as they thought. Too bad, not your fault. I would nonetheless not want to work with people that do not honour their promises.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Sound weird? What should I answer them?

Yes sounds odd, not to mention unprofessional.

Good thing you haven't left your current job yet. I suggest you:

1. **Reply back** to them saying that the contract is already signed and *not open for renegotiation*.
2. **Wait for them to reply**, if they insist on renegotiating seems that the best thing to do is to *drop the application and keep your current job* (and keep job-hunting I guess). Unless you are up to considering a lower salary.
3. **If they reply back and change their mind** about this thing they are asking, and agree to the already signed contract, then good for you. *Decide if you still want to proceed with this new job and go for it* or not.

Comment: "Decide if you still want to proceed" because they tried to stiff you before you even started, so that is a very bad sign.

Comment: @gnasher729 exactly, not my definition of starting with the right foot. If this happened before starting imagine what might come next... I'd think it twice now.